# Prepend AD user description to user belong to specific OU

Tags: powershell

the following code should work for prepend an additional description before the current content but how to do the same for every user belong to specific OU? Any suggestion?

```
get-aduser USERNAME -properties Description | ForEach-Object { Set-ADUser $_ -Description "additional data - $($_.Description)"}
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: This seems like a bad idea (those fields are separate for a reason, and there's probably a much better way to solve whatever problem this addresses), but you'll need the first part of that to select the full OU rather than just a username.

Comment: Add a desired result, as an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
get-aduser -filter * -properties Description -searchbase "DistinguishedName_to_OU_containing_Users" | ForEach-Object { Set-ADUser $_ -Description "additional data - $($_.Description)"}
```

You need the `-searchbase` parameter to narrow down your focus